# mplot3d in wxPython frame

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib

I'm writing an application in wxPython. The button "Plot" shows the wxFrame with 3D surface but I can't rotate the surface. Is it possible to rotate a 3D plot placed in a wxFrame? How can I do?

Example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx

import wx

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,  None, -1, 'CanvasFrame', size=(550,350))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NamedColor("WHITE"))

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.axes = axes3d.Axes3D(self.figure)
        X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
        self.axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
        cset = self.axes.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100)
        cset = self.axes.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40)
        cset = self.axes.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.add_toolbar()

    def add_toolbar(self):
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        if wx.Platform == '__WXMAC__':
            self.SetToolBar(self.toolbar)
        else:
            tw, th = self.toolbar.GetSizeTuple()
            fw, fh = self.canvas.GetSizeTuple()
            self.toolbar.SetSize(wx.Size(fw, th))
            self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        self.toolbar.update()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.canvas.draw()

class App(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = CanvasFrame()
        frame.Show(True)

        return True

app = App(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably be better off asking on the wxPython google group since I've seen people on there using matplotlib. Anyway, looking at the matplotlib website, it appears that there is a wxMpl module that might help: http://agni.phys.iit.edu/~kmcivor/wxmpl/

My guess is, if matplotlib can rotate the plot outside of wx, then you just need to pass some events from wx to matplotlib to make it work within wx.